# How to redirect to a new page using an object id after submitting a form in Django?

Tags: python, django

I wanted to redirect to a page that is newly created with the submission of the form. I tried and got a `NoReverseMatch` error instead.

Here's the exception raised:

> Reverse for 'receive' with keyword arguments '{'id': 15}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['receive/(?P[0-9]+)$']

Here are my views:

```py
def new_receive(request):
    """The page for adding a new receive."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = ReceiveForm()
    else:
        form = ReceiveForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_receive = form.save(commit=False)
            new_receive.save()
        return redirect('imsapp:receive', id=new_receive.id)
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'imsapp/new_receive.html', context)

def receive(request, receive_id):
    """The page for viewing a receive."""
    receive = Receive.objects.get(id=receive_id)
    receipt_no = receive.receipt_no
    date = receive.date
    context = {'receive':receive, 'receipt_no':receipt_no, 'date':date}
    return render(request, 'imsapp/receive.html', context)
```

Here are the url patterns:

```
# Page for adding a receive
path('new_receive', views.new_receive, name='new_receive'),
# Page for viewing a receive 
path('receive/<int:receive_id>', views.receive, name='receive'),
```

Comment: Please also include the URL pattern for the `'imsapp:receive'` view, and indent your code correctly so that it's readable.

Comment: alright will do

Comment: im sorry but is there a way to indent 4 spaces for the code here? i just copy paste the code

Comment: @KyleToh "is there a way to indent 4 spaces for the code here?" => select your code and click the "code" button of the wyswig editor (the braces symbol) or type ctrl+k

Comment: and your urlpath argument is defined as "receive_id", not "id" =>  `return redirect( 'imsapp:receive', receive_id=new_receive.id)`

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers thanks for your help!!

Comment: how do i close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered by @bruno desthuilliers in the comment section above

> and your urlpath argument is defined as "receive_id", not "id" =>
>   return redirect( 'imsapp:receive', receive_id=new_receive.id)